# Opening, Changing, and Saving Excel Sheets with DGV

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an application that opens an Excel Sheet using OleDB and displays it in a datagridview. Currently, I'm able to open the sheet - but am running into a problem with saving.

Here are my declarations:

```
Dim sFileName As String = "FILEPATH AND SHEET.xls"

Dim iCommand As OleDbCommand
Dim iAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter
Dim iBuilder As OleDbCommandBuilder
Dim iDs As DataSet
Dim iTable As DataTable

Dim iConnString As String = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" & sFileName & "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
Dim iConnSelect As String = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
Dim iConn As New OleDbConnection(iConnString)
```

Here's my Form Load (I'm trying to open the sheet here and use databinding to easily save):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    DataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells
    DataGridView1.Columns(4).DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.[True]

    With DataGridView1
        .Rows.Clear()
        .Columns.Clear()
    End With

    iConn.Open()
    iCommand = New OleDbCommand(iConnSelect, iConn)
    iAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(iCommand)
    iBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(iAdapter)
    iDs = New DataSet()
    iAdapter.Fill(iDs, "Incoming")
    iTable = iDs.Tables("Incoming")
    iConn.Close()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = iDs.Tables("Incoming")

    'ColumnName is a unique column with an ID
    iTable.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {iTable.Columns("ColumnName")}

    ' ADD A BUTTON AT THE LAST COLUMN IN EVERY ROW.
    Dim btn1 = New DataGridViewButtonColumn()
    btn1.HeaderText = ""
    btn1.Text = "Complete"
    btn1.Name = "btnComplete"
    btn1.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = True
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(btn1)
End Sub
```

And finally...my save button:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    iAdapter.Update(iTable)
End Sub
```

So, I expected this to save, but I'm getting this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' ocurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Dynamic SQL generation for the UpdateCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not return any key column information.

Can anyone help please? I can't figure out what's wrong. I've already tried to set a Primary Key, but I'm still getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that those exceptions mean that your select query needs to return the primary key of the table.  If your table doesn't have a primary key, you need to set one.

Comment: Ah - just tried it and I'm still getting the same error :(. I've updated my original post with the line of code. " iTable.PrimaryKey = New DataColumn() {iTable.Columns("ColumnName")}
"